# How to keep Bottle routes handling images from gridfs in mod_wsgi?

Tags: python-2.7, mod-wsgi, bottle

**Desired Behaviour**

Allow Bottle routes to handle requests for images in the format:

```
<img src="/gridfs/img/my_image.jpg">
```

On the server, this is being handled by a Bottle route and returning the image as expected:

```
@route('/gridfs/img/<filename>')
def server_gridfs_img(filename):
    # get the image
    # return it
```

**Current Behaviour**

In a local environment however, with `mod_wsgi` set up, I am getting the error:

> Internal Server Error
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>   Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>   More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>   Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

**What I've Tried**

This is my local `mod_wsgi` configuration:

```
WSGIPythonHome /var/www/html/ENV
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html:/var/www/html/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/var/www/html/wsgi
<VirtualHost *:80>

# for all content in static folder - css, js, img, fonts
Alias /static/ /var/www/html/wsgi/static/

# for rockmongo administration
Alias /rockmongo /var/www/html/rockmongo

<Directory /var/www/html/rockmongo>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/wsgi/application

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

This is my `/var/www/html/wsgi/application`:

```
from mybottleapp import application
```

**Directory**

[image]

**Question**

The rest of the routes in my application seem to be being honored.

It doesn't seem that Bottle is handling the requests for images like `/gridfs/img/my_image.jpg` though.

How can I make that happen?

**UPDATE**

Looked at Apache error log and saw this:

```
CorruptGridFile: no chunk #1
```

I am troubleshooting that now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the solution to the updated situation mentioned above here:

[How to mongodump from OpenShift and mongorestore locally on MongoDB 2.4.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160237/how-to-mongodump-from-openshift-and-mongorestore-locally-on-mongodb-2-4-9)

The data corruption was caused from exporting and importing with RockMongo - apparently sometimes there can be issues with this approach and larger data sets.