# How to mongodump from OpenShift and mongorestore locally on MongoDB 2.4.9?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I just did this myself (as a RockMongo export and import was corrupted) so just posting here.

Note this was for MongoDB verison 2.4.9 with corresponding versions of `mongodump` and `mongorestore`.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, this is very helpful.  I'm actually going to try to use this as a guide to follow but in reverse: I have a local `mongodump` and want to do upload via SCP then do a `mongorestore` in openshift.  Do you happen to know how to do that?  I can't seem to find any resources on this.  I'm wondering if I do that will it just create a new mongo DB and will I somehow have to change some environment variables to point to that new DB. (The reason I'm going through this is that I'm migrating my app from Heroku to OpenShift).  Thanks!

Comment: This is from an old post, so be sure to read the official docs around the subject and back up before you take any action etc, but it might be helpful to reflect on the logic involved:  https://forums.openshift.com/how-to-perform-mongorestore-on-openshift-online

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Read the documentation relevant to your versions first, backup, make sure the solution below is relevant to your scenario etc.

http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/program/mongodump/
http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/program/mongorestore/

**Getting the OC command line interface**

The steps below use the OpenShift command line interface (to run the `oc` commands).

The download link for your relevant operating system can be found by going to:

`OpenShift Online Console` > `[Click on help icon]` > `Command Line Tools`

That location also contains the command required to login.

It looks something like this:

```
oc login https://api.pro-ap-southeast-2.openshift.com --token=******
```

You can then run the following to display all the pods in your project:

```
oc get pods
```

---

**BEGIN 20/11/18 update**

I just had to revisit these steps again, the following may be helpful to others:

`01)`  To view all MongoDB environment variables, from local computer run:

```
oc exec mongodb-XX-XXXXX env
```

(gleaned from comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40538048))

`02)`  To perform the dump, go to pod terminal in openshift console:

`OpenShift Online Console` > `Applications` > `Pods` > `MongoDB-**-*****` > `Terminal`

and enter this:

```
mongodump --host MONGODB_SERVICE_HOST:MONGODB_SERVICE_PORT --username admin --password "MONGODB_ADMIN_PASSWORD"
```

replacing the variable names with the actual values displayed from running the previous command.

I had to use the username `admin` rather than the environment variable value for `MONGODB_USER`.

I got this returned in terminal when running the above command:

```
2023-01-14T06:09:37.689+0000    writing admin.system.users to 
2023-01-14T06:09:37.690+0000    done dumping admin.system.users (2 documents)
2023-01-14T06:09:37.690+0000    writing admin.system.version to 
2023-01-14T06:09:37.692+0000    done dumping admin.system.version (2 documents)
2023-01-14T06:09:37.692+0000    writing <my-db-name-1>.<my-collection-name-1> to 
2023-01-14T06:09:37.692+0000    writing <my-db-name-2>.<my-collection-name-2> to 
2023-01-14T06:09:37.692+0000    writing <my-db-name-3>.<my-collection-name-3> to 
2023-01-14T06:09:37.692+0000    writing users.users to 
2023-01-14T06:09:37.694+0000    done dumping <my-db-name-1>.<my-collection-name-1> (100 documents)
2023-01-14T06:09:37.694+0000    writing <my-db-name-4>.<my-collection-name-4> to 
2023-01-14T06:09:37.695+0000    done dumping <my-db-name-4>.<my-collection-name-4> (3 documents)
2023-01-14T06:09:37.695+0000    writing <my-db-name-5>.<my-collection-name-5> to 
2023-01-14T06:09:37.696+0000    done dumping <my-db-name-5>.<my-collection-name-5> (1 document)
2023-01-14T06:09:37.707+0000    done dumping users.users (6 documents)
2023-01-14T06:09:37.709+0000    done dumping <my-db-name-3>.<my-collection-name-3> (13 documents)
2023-01-14T06:09:37.716+0000    done dumping <my-db-name-2>.<my-collection-name-2> (78 documents)
```

`03)`  If you want to zip the dump folder, do this from pod terminal in console:

```
# sanity check to see where you are
pwd  
# returns /opt/app-root/src

# list the directory contents
ls 
# returns dump 

# zip the folder 
tar czf my_dump.tar.gz dump

# list the directory contents again
ls
# returns dump  my_dump.tar.gz
```

(gleaned from comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27722053))

`04)`  To download the folder, from local PC terminal, do this:

```
oc rsync mongodb-20-XXXXX:/opt/app-root/src/dump /c/Users/Your-Directory
```

Or if you want to download the zip file instead, do this:

```
oc rsync mongodb-20-XXXXX:/opt/app-root/src/my_dump.tar.gz /c/Users/Your-Directory
```

(gleaned from [official docs](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/dev_guide/copy_files_to_container.html) and [blog post here](https://blog.openshift.com/transferring-files-in-and-out-of-containers-in-openshift-part-1-manually-copying-files/))

For reference, if you wanted to do a `mongoexport` of a collection to a `.json` file (as opposed to a `mongodump` of all databases), you can do the following from the pod terminal and then download the file using `oc rsync` as shown above:

```
mongoexport --host ***.**.**.** --port 27017 --authenticationDatabase admin --username admin --password "*******" --db <your-db-name> --collection <your-collection-name> --out my_collection_export.json
```

Random update (14/01/23):

Annoyingly, I cannot see what version of `mongodump` is being used when I run the following from the pod terminal:

```
mongodump --version
mongodump version: built-without-version-string
git version: built-without-git-spec
Go version: go1.8.5
   os: linux
   arch: amd64
   compiler: gc
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
```

So I don't know if that will be problematic when it comes to doing a `mongorestore` and needing to ensure that the `mongodump` and `mongorestore` versions are compatible :/.

**END 20/11/18 update**

---

**SSH In**

```
rhc ssh [app-name]
cd app-root/repo/
```

Check what version of mongodump you have:

```
mongodump --version
mongodump version 2.4.9
```

**mongodump**

The command below will dump *ALL* databases.

```
mongodump --host $OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT --username $OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME --password $OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD
```

**Zip Dump Folder**

```
zip -r dump.zip dump
```

**Exit SSH**

```
exit
```

**Download via SCP**

(Replace the environment variable below with the actual value).

```
scp OPENSHIFT_APP_UUID@appname-username.rhcloud.com:~/app-root/repo/dump.zip /var/www/html
```

**SSH back in and delete dump files**

```
rhc ssh [app-name]
cd app-root/repo/
rm -r dump 
rm -r dump.zip
```

In local command line, go to the directory where you downloaded the zip file:

```
cd /var/www/html
```

**Unzip Dump Folder**

```
unzip dump.zip -d dump
```

See what version of mongorestore you have and that everything is compatible:

```
mongorestore --version
mongorestore version 2.4.9
```

At this point, I deleted all my local *corresponding* databases in RockMongo so that the restore process would create them from scratch.

**mongorestore**

```
mongorestore dump
```

The default host and port used is `localhost` and `27017`.

Comment: You can also use rhc scp to download
rhc scp dev download {localpath} {remotepath}