# How to download a file/folder from remote (openshift) to local system

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

How to download or backup or to save a copy of a file from openshift remote folder into my local-system folder using rhc client tool? or is there any other way other than rhc client tool to make a backup of it to my local system?

Also, Is there a way to copy an entire folder from remote(openshift) to local?

Comment: I tried this one which helped me., rhc scp app_name download /path/to/local/folder /path/to/remote/folder/file., but how to download a folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use winscp (if on windows) to ssh into your openshift app. Navigate to your folder. Drag and drop folder or files to local machine.

Filezilla - [using filezilla and sftp with openshift](https://blog.openshift.com/using-filezilla-and-sftp-on-windows-with-openshift/)

Comment: I use linux. i tried gigolo to connect the openshift remote file system but no sftp support and permission denied error when i click var folder. Is there anything like winscp for linux.

Comment: Try Filezilla on linux.

Comment: I tried filezilla and also found a blog related to filezilla setting up with openshift.... works nice. It seems I accidentally uploaded some files through terminal ., able to view all, delete, retrieve files/folders. Thanks @fatfantasma.

Answer (score 13):

First, `tar` and `gzip` your folder on the server within a `ssh` session, the syntax is:

```
rhc ssh <app_name>
tar czf <name_of_new_file>.tar.gz <name_of_directory>
```

Second, after you have disconnected from the openshift server (with `CTRL-D`), download this file to your local system:

```
rhc scp <app_name> download <local_destination> <absolute_path_to_remote_file>
```

Then on your local machine you can extract the file and perform your actions.

Comment: For this "tar czf <name_of_new_file>.tar.gz <name_of_directory>"

Comment: I am trying to run the first command in MongoDB pod on OpenShift with `tar czf my_dump.tar.gz dump` and it returns `tar: Old option `g' requires an argument.` I also tried `zip -r dump.zip dump` and got `zip: command not found`.

Comment: Actually, this works from pod terminal in OpenShift Online console:  `tar czf my_dump.tar.gz dump`.

Answer (score 3):

теперь можно так

> copy a pod directory to a local directory:

```
oc rsync <pod-name>:/opt/app-root/src /c/source
```

https://docs.okd.io/3.11/dev_guide/copy_files_to_container.html