# List of all environment variables for a Pod

Tags: openshift-origin

I have a web app on OpenShift v3 (all-in-One), using the Wildfly Builder Image. In addition, I created a service named xyz, to point to an external host+IP. Something like this:

```
        "kind": "Service",
        "apiVersion": "v1",
        "metadata": { "name": "xyz" },
        "spec": {
            "ports": [
                {   "port": 61616,
                    "protocol": "TCP",
                    "targetPort": 61616
                }
            ],
            "selector": {}
        }
```

I also have an endpoint, pointing externally, but that is not relevant for this question.

When deployed, my program can access an environment variable named **XYZ_PORT=tcp://172.30.192.186:61616**

However, I cannot figure out how to see **all** the values of all such variables either via the web-console, or using the CLI.  Using the web-console, I cannot see it being injected into the YAML.

I tried some of the **oc env** options, but none seem to list what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you are deploying kitchensink, then the below CLI should list all the environment variables:

```
oc env bc/kitchensink --list
```

Comment: You possibly meant ``oc set env dc/kitchensink --list``. Doing it on ``bc`` shows build time environment variables. This also will not show all the environment variables set automatically by Docker, which is what environment variable in question which is referenced looks to be. Would need to run ``env`` in the running pod as something like ``oc exec pod/kitchensink-a1b23 env`` to see all that were set in pod.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton: Thank you. Can you please convert that to an answer, for posterity :).  One thing though:  I did not use the command exactly as specified. It said slashes were not allowed in the name. Instead, I used oc exec podname -c containername env

Comment: Correct, ``oc exec`` only takes a pod name, so ``pod/`` wasn't needed. Was typing it from memory. :-)

Comment: Why is `set` used instead of `get` for *viewing* variables?

Comment: For reference, following Graham's suggestion, I had to use this to view all envars for MongoDB:  `oc exec mongodb-20-xxxx env`

Comment: Yeah, weird on the `set` part,  but hey - it works.  Thanks.